# Size of the void functions

Tags: c

I have come across the void functions in c.
And I understood that these functions wont return any value but will be having a return statement.
I have tried to see the size of the function with the sizeof operator.
The value is printed was 1 as size of void function.
Can anyone explain how the 1 is the size of the function??

The below is the program i have used.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_func() 
{
   printf("From void my_function\n");
   return ;
}

int func()
{
    printf("From int func\n");
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
   printf("Size of void function : %lu\n",sizeof(my_func())); // 1 is printed
   printf("Size of integer function : %lu\n",sizeof(func())); // 4 is printed

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pleas format and indent code properly. Machine can read any code, humans cannot.

Comment: Where did you learn the term "void functions"?

Comment: Hi larson,
I am looking for that reason why the value is 1 for void?

Comment: Note that in general `sizeof(my_func())` does not yield the size of the function itself (i.e. the number of bytes of machine code, or anything like that) but rather the size of the the type that it returns.  Here `my_func()` returns `void` so you get the size of the type `void`, which is an error in standard C but some compilers (e.g. gcc) make it 1 as an extension, see the linked question.  In your second example, `sizeof(func())` is just giving you the size of `int`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: It's not an uncommon synonym for "function returning void".

Comment: Hey Sourav,

I mean the functions with return type as void(non returning functions).

Thanks

Comment: Well no, you *cannot* get the size of `void`, because that is an incomplete type.  If you apply the `sizeof` operator to it, you get undefined behavior.  In fact, such a use of `sizeof` is a constraint violation, so a conforming implementation must also emit a diagnostic.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for reply.

I understood like, void is a datatype and its size is 1.
So only the output is printing as 1.

Is this correct?

Comment: Well, it acts like a datatype, but it's a very special one in that you can't actually have any objects of that type.  As I said before, whether "its size is 1" depends on the dialect of C you are using.  In standard C, `void` does not have a size and `sizeof(myfunc())` would cause a compiler error (or technically a "diagnostic").  Some compilers intentionally deviate from the standard and say that `void` does have a size after all and that it is 1; on such a compiler `sizeof(my_func())` indeed yields 1.

Comment: So your compiler is presumably one of the second kind.  Technically speaking, your program is not valid in the C language, but only in the "dialect" of C that your compiler provides.